# Keep certain files only in remote?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

I'm synchronizing my dotfiles with GitHub and I want to have a `README.md` and a `LICENSE` in my GitHub repo, but I do not want to pull/push them on my local machine (since they then pollute my `$HOME` directory).

How can I keep these files uniquely on GitHub, such that:

- Them being missing in my `$HOME` directory is ignored when I do a `git push` (instead of giving an error about the local and remote repositories being out of sync)
- They are not downloaded when I do a `git pull`

Comment: Out of curiosity: How would you ever be able to update the readme?

Comment: From inside Github's editor. I mean, ideally I would be able to pull the README and the LICENSE, but I want that to not be the default behavior.

Comment: Ignoring files may help but think this is more trouble than it is worth https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/